# Printf(%s) prints 0

Tags: c, string, numbers, printf

I have this command in my project (in C):

```
int addFinalDataStr(char* value) 
{
    fprintf(objFile,"%-7.7s\n",value);
    fflush(objFile);
}
```

When I call this method with the value like: `"60100"`, it prints `"60100"` with no problems, 
but when i call it with a string like `"37777777773"` it just prints out `"0"`.

Comment: Have you checked return value? It shouldn't be negative.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Just tried it on code pad and it worked for me... (http://codepad.org/1hzQE2EC)

Comment: Show us a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem. http://sscce.org/. Does the problem show up if you use `printf` rather than `fprintf(objFile, ...)`? Have you tried tweaking the format string?

Answer (score 0):

I think the your error is caused by the compiler check with another compiler (I recommend you the GCC compiler) and see if it works.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to blame the compiler (or the runtime library, for that matter). We need a complete self-contained program.

Answer (score 0):

There are **2** issues

```
printf("%-7.7s\n", "60100");
// should print "60100  ", not "60100" as OP states

printf("%-7.7s\n", "37777777773");
// should print "3777777", not "0".
```

It appears the compiler is not compliant or something critical is missing from the post.